# Why were parentheses disambiguated as a function declaration with std::istream_iterator?

Tags: c++, declaration, function-declaration, ambiguity

```
auto queue = [](string str) {
    istringstream ss(str);
    //std::copy(std::istream_iterator<string>(ss),
    //          std::istream_iterator<string>(),
    //          std::ostream_iterator<string>(std::cout, " "));

    //deque<string> q(std::istream_iterator<string>(ss), std::istream_iterator<string>{});
    deque<string> q(std::istream_iterator<string>(ss), std::istream_iterator<string>());
    return q;
};
```

Why would the compiler complain

> parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration
> [-Wvexing-parse]

if I construct a container with `istream_iterator<string>()`.

Is there any difference with parameters in `std::copy` and container constructor?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: `q` is a function that takes two arguments; an iterator "ss",  and an unnamed function taking no arguments and returning an iterator. It returns a `deque`.

Comment: `std::istream_iterator<string>()` *can* be an unnamed parameter in a function declaration. And if it can, `q` must be treated as a function. If you have `{}` or `" "`, those are obvious values, so cannot be part of a function declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
 deque<string> q(std::istream_iterator<string>(ss),
                 std::istream_iterator<string>());
```

is a function declaration with the return type `deque<string>` and two parameters of the type `std::istream_iterator<string>`. The first parameter has the name ss and the second parameter is unnamed.

To make this line a declaration of the variable q you should write either

```
 deque<string> q( ( std::istream_iterator<string>(ss) ),
                  (  std::istream_iterator<string>() ) );
```

or

```
 deque<string> q(std::istream_iterator<string>{ ss },
                 std::istream_iterator<string>{});
```

In this case there are used expressions instead of parameter declarations.

You may include declarators in parentheses. For example

```
int ( x );
```

When a declaration is a parameter declaration then you may omit a declarator like

```
int()
```

Here is an example of three declarations of the same function.

```
int f( int( x ) );
int f( int x );
int f( int( x ) )
{
    return 2 * x;
}
```

Comment: Why not go even further and replace *all* constructor call parenthesis with braces? I like me some consistency, and it avoids all variants of the Most Vexing Parse.

Comment: @DevSolar - It instead gets you into the *almost* uniform initialization, where `vector<int> v(1, 2);` and `vector<int> v{1, 2};` creates different sized vectors.  :-(

Comment: The second parameter is parameterless and unnamed function of no arguments.